# Can I lookup a PNR without going through the relevant airline's website?

Tags: air-travel, bookings

I have a flight reservation, and I know my PNR (confirmation number, booking code, etc.).  Unfortunately, it seems I cannot look up my reservation on the airline's website (they are a small airline and their website does not offer this functionality).

> Is there any reputable website where I can look up my reservation, given, say, my PNR and first and last name (or other information I should have)?

With a quick internet search, I found a few sites which claim to provide this function, though I don't like the idea of entering in my PNR to random websites and hoping for the best (they could easily use this information to cancel my flight and collect $$$ from the airline for it).

I'd like to keep this question general so that answers are useful to others, but here is my specific situation.  I booked a flight, got a confirmation email, with PNR, etc., and then changed my flight by emailing customer service.  They emailed back telling me they had changed my flight, but didn't provide any other sort of confirmation.  Obviously I can just email back and ask for a ticket/itinerary summary, but I can imagine a situation (e.g. urgent travel) where it would be extremely helpful to be able to look up a flight reservation without going through the airline that issued it (or which is operating the flight).

Answer (score 3):

There are several sites to look up PNRs that are run by the major [GDS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_distribution_system) (Global Distribution System) providers. While I cannot vouch for their security, they are run by the same companies that run the ticketing systems, and are therefore more likely to be reliable than mere "random websites":

- [Sabre Virtually There](https://www.virtuallythere.com)
- [Travelport ViewTrip](https://www.viewtrip.com/VTHome.aspx) (Apollo or Galileo)
- [Amadeus Check My Trip](https://www.checkmytrip.com/cmtweb/web-desktop.html#/login) (you'll need to create an account or download their app first)

Not all airlines use these systems and not all reservations are visible through these sites, so there's no guarantee you'll find your PNR, but it's worth a try.

Comment: I think these only allow you to look up bookings made through their system.  I just tried some of my upcoming flight bookings without luck in the first two, too lazy to create an account to test Amadeus.

Comment: @Irked Yes, it only shows bookings contained within a particular GDS, and some airlines (especially LCCs) don't use the major GDS systems so those won't show up at all.