# Booking gallore - Who should I ask to get my Booking Number?

Tags: bookings, greece, aegean-airlines

We are going to be flying with Aegean Airlines (great company so far, albeit a bit pricey) from Greece to Munich. This time, I reserved the tickets through a travel agency, but I haven't been provided a Reservation Reference (Booking Number), required to check myself online.

Who should I ask to have a booking number issued, as the queue at the Aegean checkin desk in Makedonia Airport is too long for me to not go prepared.

Comment: Have you asked your travel agency? They might even expect to do your check-in for you.

Comment: What other information about the flights do you have?

Comment: @NateEldredge Only an informational letter saying "Point of meeting: TIcket desk"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Closely related: *[Can I lookup a PNR without going through the relevant airline's website?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/103262)*

Your travel agent should be able to provide you with your booking reference / record locator / passenger name record (PNR), and is probably the easiest to get a hold of.

Note that Aegean also allows you to check in online using your ticket number or using a tour operator booking reference, if your travel agent has provided you with either of those.

If you have a Miles + Bonus account and that number was submitted with your reservation, you may try logging in to that account to see if it is there.

If not, it is a straightforward matter to call the airline directly and ask; the agent will likely ask you some questions to confirm your identity first. It is extremely common for them to look up reservations using your name, travel dates, and itinerary (points of origin and destination and/or flight numbers).

Comment: Yeah, I have been provided no referrence of booking what so ever. Will login to my M+B account to check if it has been registered. Should no other (such well written) answer appear, I will be accepting yours. Thanks :)