# Alitalia and baggages

Tags: air-travel, luggage, alitalia

For the first time after years of travelling I will fly with Alitalia.

I booked it via Expedia, and now I can't find anywhere any information on baggage in my reservation. Neither on Expedia or Alitalia website, I can't find the baggage number included in my reservation. The only info I found is in Expedia confirmation which states "economy/touristic (O) class".

I find it really disappointing that my flight info on Alitalia's website doesn't say anything more than flight times and seats. With every company I've flew with I could always find the baggage info somewhere. With Alitalia it's impossible.

I'm just afraid that once at the checkin counter at the airport I will find out that there are no baggage included in the reservation and I have to pay them there.

Is there any way (except from the expensive call to customer service) to check the number of bags included in my reservation?

Comment: This page https://www.alitalia.com/en_gb/fly-alitalia/baggage/checked-baggage.html states that unless you have a "light" fare, you are entitled to 1 x 23 kg. You may also want to check your e-ticket receipt. Probably not as easy to read, but it should have the information somewhere.

Comment: I checked my expedia receipt, which is the only receipt I got, and it doesn't say anything about bags

Comment: Not sure if Alitalia have completed their migration to Sabre yet or not. You may want to try https://www.virtuallythere.com/ to see if you get more details.

Comment: See https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/103262/can-i-lookup-a-pnr-without-going-through-the-relevant-airlines-website for the equivalent tools for the other GDS.

Comment: I tried all of those services but none of them finds the reservation.. thanks anyway

Comment: Interestingly, the "Light" fares don't have a dedicated booking class, so it's not possible just from the O to determine whether you have a light fare or not. Try the options to purchase additional luggage in the flight management section on the Alitalia website to see if they say anything there. Not that if you are able to select a seat, it's not a light fare.

Comment: @jcaron I selected my seat indeed. I didn't think about it actually!! thanks for suggesting!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alitalia's hold luggage policy is as follows:

[image: Alitalia luggage policy]

The [light offer](https://www.alitalia.com/en_it/offerte/tutte-le-offerte/offerta-light.html) is generally the cheapest option and includes:

> - Web and Fast Check-in
> - Hand baggage
> - Seat allocation
> - Snack and drinks
> - Main airports
> - Earn Miles

So, one method you can use to know if your fare includes hold luggage, is to check if you are able to select a seat on the flight without having to pay. If so, your fare is not a Light fare, and therefore you should have hold luggage included. Indeed, [according to the Alitalia Terms and Conditions for the Light fare](https://www.alitalia.com/en_it/offers/all-offers/light-offers-terms-and-conditions.html),

> - The light fare does not allow you to choose or change the seat that is automatically assigned; [...]
> - Seat change is allowed for a fee on the Alitalia website during online check-in and in the "My Flights" section if allowed by the system; in all remaining cases the seat will be assigned automatically. The fares for the seat change are:
>
>   - Domestic and international flights: €5 per flight;
>   - Flights to US and Canada: €20 per flight;
>   - Flights from US and Canada: US$25 per flight